# Android, How do I pass a variable as a pointer to a function?

Tags: java, android

How do I pass a variable as a pointer to a function?
I have the following code that I wish to refactor

```
    public static HttpResponse getJSONEntityFromURL(Context context, String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        httpget.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpget.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        HttpResponse response;

        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        return response;
    }
```

to something like this

```
    public static HttpResponse getJSONEntityFromURL(Context context, String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            setHeaders(httpget);
        HttpResponse response;

        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        return response;
    }

private static void setHeaders(HttpRequestBase httpget) {
    httpget.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpget.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
}
```

I'm assuming that I need to pass the httpget paramater as a pointer?

Comment: you cannot, there is no such thing in java. you could use an interface, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm assuming that I need to pass the httpget paramater as a pointer?

No, because Java does not have pointers.

The code you have there seems fine -- you are passing the `HttpGet` object to `setHeaders()` and calling methods upon it. If you are having specific problems with your current syntax, please explain.

Comment: Ahh, that explains why I was struggling to work out how to pass in a pointer :) Does the same apply for native types or just objects?

Comment: @jamesw: Primitives (`int`, `float`, `boolean`, etc.) are pass-by-value. Objects (`Integer`, `Float`, `Boolean`, `HttpGet`) are pass-by-reference.

Comment: That clears up a whole lot of confusion. I had seen that changes to primitive types were not reflected in the calling method so I assumed the same would apply for an object. Everything suddenly becomes clear

Answer (score 1):

I would use that

```
private static void setHeaders(final HttpRequestBase httpget) {
  httpget.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  httpget.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
}
```

sure it isn't a pointer, but in this case the reference httpget is changed without returning the HttpRequestBase.

Comment: Thanks, That is a big help in my quest for knowledge

Comment: @StefanBe: `static` is not a valid modifier for a method parameter in Java. Leastways, Java complains with a compiler error. Did you mean `final`?

Answer (score 1):

Java only allows you pass references, since Java doesn't implements pointer arithmetic

All primitive types are passed by copy, and all object types are passed by ref. (By copy, but the copy of the memory address instead of duplicating the whole object.)

the way you did i believe is the correct one:

```
private static void setHeaders(HttpRequestBase AGet) {
    AGet.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    AGet.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
}
```

Unless you gonna need to use this method somewhere else I recommend the first code.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html <- documentation

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HttpMessage interface as seen below: -

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpMessage.html

This will allow you to accept an implementation of this interface, i.e. an instance of HttpGet

i.e: -

```
private static void setHeaders(HttpMessage httpMessage) 
{
    httpMessage.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpMessage.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
}
```